# What is the most esy way to know if an object is moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to know ,in code, let `say in update()` function when an object is moving instead of being at rest, I want to use the least resource expensive way of doing it. Note that I am moving the object using `Vector3.MoveTwords()` function. 
I apologize for the vagueness of the question.

Comment: define `moving`

Comment: @AndyT Changing position (x,y,z)....

Comment: so you need to check if position changed compared with the last frame? how would you do this? probably by storing current pos in member variable and compare it with new current next frame?

Comment: The least resource intensive way of doing it? Hook into the code that's updating its position?!

Comment: The question is somewhat vague, but I don't agree with the number of downvotes, honestly.

Comment: Are you using the physics simulation, or moving/translating objects via script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to detect any changes made to the transform of an object (position, rotation, scale), you can use the `hasChanged` flag of the transform :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (transform.hasChanged)
        {
            print("The transform has changed!");
            transform.hasChanged = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Source https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-hasChanged.html

Answer (score 2):

If the object have `RigidBody` component, then you can check for

`RigidBody.velocity == Vector3.zero`

Else you can save a Vector3 position every frame and match it with current position as follows

```
Vector3 prevPos;
public void update(){
    if(prevPos == transform.position){
        Debug.Log("Object Moving");
    }
    prevPos = transform.position;
}
```

Comment: You should read on about testing equality for non integer numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [`IsSleeping`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.IsSleeping.html) if you are using a `RigidBody`

```
Rigidbody.IsSleeping()
```

[From the Unity Manual:](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RigidbodiesOverview.html)

> When a Rigidbody is moving slower than a defined minimum linear or rotational speed, the physics engine assumes it has come to a halt. When this happens, the GameObject does not move again until it receives a collision or force, and so it is set to “sleeping” mode.